# Odd compiler error, Davlik error 1 from java.net.DatagramPacket.class

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I suddenly started getting an unusual compiler error and is it making impossible to do any testing, I am running Eclipse with the plugin and compiling on the 2.1 version.

[2010-08-11 00:29:38 - PeriodTrackerv2] 
trouble processing "java/net/DatagramPacket.class":
[2010-08-11 00:29:38 - PeriodTrackerv2] 
Attempt to include a core class (java.* or javax.*) in something other
...
[2010-08-11 00:29:38 - PeriodTrackerv2] 1 error; aborting
[2010-08-11 00:29:38 - PeriodTrackerv2] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

I verified that this class does exist in the standard Android2.1 jar file, so I find it highly unusual a class in the actual base Jar file would be problematic.  I am not using this class in any fashion in my program.

I updated to version 2.2 and still get same error, this completely baffles me and just appeared tonight after zero issues for months.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Alright!

I reviewed the build path and somehow the Android.jar was added twice.  Problem solved.